# Is there a WPF show/hide panel component?

Tags: c#, wpf, components

I'm looking for a show/hide component, much like the toolbox from VS2010 and eclipse's panels when something is maximized. Could anybody please point me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[WPF Docking Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFdockinglib.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try WPF [Expande](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Control:

```
<Expander>
  Content
</Expander>
```